# add http request header an WSO2 proxy service

Tags: wso2, esb, apache-synapse

I have a proxy service who uses an XSLT mediator, I want to add a request header to it, this information representes a basic HTTP authentication : 
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
The last key is created with a login 'admin' and a password 'admin'.
How can I add this header to my request in the proxy service as a get request so I can authenticate my proxy before doing the xslt transformation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> How can I add this header to my request
> ```

You should add this as BasicAuth header in your request. If you use SOAP UI, you can see the options to add a S[OAPHeader elements](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html) where, provide as Authorization :Basic XXX

Comment: This is for testing my proxy service but what I want is to add this header in my proxy so it could authenticate before transforming data with XSLT. Because I can't get data from my server without athenticating.

Comment: Check this post http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/09/executing-carbon-admin-services-from.html You can use property mediator to add this